# ckeditor default target link=" _blank" not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

***My ckeditor version is 4.4.7***

I want to change the default target to every link of the text that I add to ckeditor and I found this code

```js
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {

  try {

    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if (dialogName == 'link') {

      var informationTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('target');

      var targetField = informationTab.get('linkTargetType');

      targetField['default'] = '_blank';

    }

  } catch (exception) {

    alert('Error ' + ev.message);

  }

});

CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
  var editor = ev.editor,
    dataProcessor = editor.dataProcessor,
    htmlFilter = dataProcessor && dataProcessor.htmlFilter;
  htmlFilter.addRules({
    a: function(element) {
      element.attributes['target'] = "_blank";
    }
  });
});
```

I added this code to link.js file of ckeditor folder and it's working
but not correctly

I mean if I copy the text that have a link from word to editor,it doesn't add target_blank to a href automatically

but I have to click 'edit link' on it and see the default target already on _blank

[image]

then I click ok and save then it works.

but I want it to auto set target="_blank" on every link that I copy from word.

anyone can help?

thanks.

Comment: which version you are use ?

Comment: my version is 4.4.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I added this code to link.js file of ckeditor folder and it's working but not correctly

You use this code directly on HTML page were you initialize the editor and **not** in `link.js` file:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', { });
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
...
```

Comment: I edit default.js of 'pastefromword' plugin instead so I don't have to edit every pages of my website but thanks for your advice!

Comment: You can also add it to `config.js` (below the `CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {...};`) so that you don't have to update your filter with every editor update.

Answer (score 3):

Editing inside plugin files is not an ideal solution.

The best solution would be to add this to your js file

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
   var dialogName = ev.data.name;
   var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
      if ( dialogName == 'link' ) {
          var targetTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'target' );
          var targetField = targetTab.get( 'linkTargetType' );
          targetField[ 'default' ] = '_blank';
      }
});
```

Comment: I had to use this `$(document).ready(function ()` so you may need to do the same.

Comment: This works for other defaults, too. For example, setting the default protocol to `https://` looks like 

`var linkInfoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');`

`var protocolField = linkInfoTab.get('protocol');`

`protocolField['default'] = 'https://';`

Answer (score 2):

Where did you put your code?

I changed

```
type : 'select',
id : 'linkTargetType',
label : commonLang.target,
'default' : 'notSet',
```

in `_source\plugins\link\dialogs\link.js` to

```
type : 'select',
id : 'linkTargetType',
label : commonLang.target,
'default' : '_blank',
```

and this works fine.

Comment: I tried your way but there's still the same problem.It won't open a new window unless click 'edit link' on the link in the editor.